# Using fgets() to write a blank line in struct

Tags: c

When reading a file I'd like to also read its blank lines but it's not working:

```
while(fgets(line, 25, file) != NULL) {
   sscanf(line, "%s", fooStruct.text);
}
```

Is there another way to read blank lines from text?

Comment: Another way... Like using `getc()` to read characters one-by-one?

Comment: calculate the length of string in `line` if it is 1, it means it read only the `newline character`, then you can appropriately add the `newline character` in your file to denote blank line.

Comment: If you are not concerned with only storing a single word in `fooStruct.txt` and want instead the whole line, then the following will work as well: `while(fgets(fooStruct.txt, 25, file) != NULL) {}` and will include blank lines.

Comment: the call to `fgets()` read the blank lines just fine.  The resulting buffer `line` would contain: `\n' '\0'.  However, the call to `sscanf()` with the '%s' format specifier will not input the '\n' so the `fooStruct.text` will receive only the '\0' appended by the `sscanf()` function

Answer (score 1):

If the line is blank, then `sscanf` will return 0, to indicate that no conversions where successfully completed. In that case, you can just set the `text` to an empty string

```
while(fgets(line, 25, file) != NULL) {
    if ( sscanf(line, "%s", fooStruct.text) != 1 )
        fooStruct.text[0] = '\0';   // sscanf failed, must be a blank line
}
```

Comment: my understanding is that sscanf() with a '%s' format specifier will always append a NUL byte, so no need to specifically insert a NUL byte.

Comment: @user3629249 That's only if `sscanf` succeeds. When `sscanf` fails, as is the case here, the output buffer is not modified, and contains whatever garbage it started with.